# App crashes whenever I try to add dependency of AdMob

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, admob

I am in the process of creating a software application. Initially, my application was fully developed and functioning properly. Later, I attempted to incorporate Google AdMob functionality into my application by following the guidelines provided in this article: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk.

However, I am currently encountering a problem. Whenever I attempt to run my application after including the following dependency in module level gradle:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
My application crashes and displays the following error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.tayyabssolutions.statussaverforwhatsapp, PID: 7327 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *

* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.  
*******************************************************************************
```

complete code of my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/status_saver"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/status_saver_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StatusSaverForWhatsapp"
        tools:targetApi="31">




<activity
android:name=".Activities.TabbedView"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gsm.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
          android:value="@string/test_app_id"
          />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

code for my Module level gradle is

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.tayyabssolutions.statussaverforwhatsapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tayyabssolutions.statussaverforwhatsapp"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding  true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.19.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.1.0'



}
```

where as code for my project gradle is

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Status Saver For Whatsapp"
include ':app'
```

I tried to delete dependency. When I delete the dependency app works fine.

Comment: As mentioned check the APP ID is correctly created and also try to test the APP ID directly

Comment: Thanks alot. it helped and now my aps is working fine

Comment: Great, Can you mention what you did to resolve here as well

Comment: app id was wrong @Arul